# Actionscript 3 Using Regular Expressions to replace words in string

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a project that involves creating an Adobe Flash application that changes the tense of the text in an input text box. 
The original example text is: 
"The city of Atlantis is lost. The werewolves were to blame. I am saddened and so were my friends. The residents and Atlantis are unhappy too. It is such a waste."

I've figured out how to make it past tense and mostly present tense. But I can't seem to figure out how to change the part "I was" from past tense back to present tense (I am). Please help.

```
    original_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ConvertOriginal);
    past_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ConvertPast);
    present_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ConvertPresent);

    function ConvertOriginal(e:MouseEvent):void {
        body_txt.text = "The city of Atlantis is lost. The werewolves were to blame. I am saddened and so were my friends. The residents and Atlantis are unhappy too. It is such a waste."; 
}
    function ConvertPast(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var myPattern1:RegExp = /\s(is|am)\s/g;  
        var str:String = body_txt.text;
        body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern1, " was ");
        var myPattern2:RegExp = /\sare\s/g;  
        body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern2, " were "); 
}
    function ConvertPresent(e:MouseEvent):void {
        var myPattern1:RegExp = /\swas\s/g;  
        var str:String = body_txt.text;
        body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern1, " is ");
        var myPattern2:RegExp = /was/g;
        body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern2, " I am ");
        var myPattern3:RegExp = /\swere\s/g;  
        body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern3, " are ");
}
```

Comment: use word boundaries `\b` instead of `\s` and in the replacement part, you don't need to add spaces.

Comment: Thank you, Avinash Raj. But how do change "I was" back to "I am". I keep getting "I is" because of the \bwas\b being replaced by "is"

Comment: sorry I'm so weak in Grammar part..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this order of regex replacements:

1. `\bI was\b` with `I am`
2. `\bwas\b` with `is`
3. `\bwere\b` with `are`

Here is your modified function:

```
function ConvertPresent(e:MouseEvent):void {
    var myPattern1:RegExp = /\bI was\b/g;  
    var str:String = body_txt.text;
    body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern1, "I am");
    var myPattern2:RegExp = /\bwas\b/g;
    body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern2, "is");
    var myPattern3:RegExp = /\bwere\b/g;  
    body_txt.text = body_txt.text.replace(myPattern3, "are");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string replacement methods to convert it, something like this

```
private function replaceAll(pattern:*,replacementStr:String,originalString:String):String {
        if (originalString!= null) {
            while (originalString.search(pattern) != -1) {
                originalString= originalString.replace(pattern,replacementStr);
            }
        }
        return originalString;
    }
```